# How to resolve dependences when one module depends on another?

Tags: java, scala, maven

I have maven multiple-module project.

```
A: parent.
    B: app.
    C: utils.
```

In Module B, I make a fat jar with below configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>com.xxx.MainRun</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

When I run fat jar of Module B, I get a ClassNotFound error and the class is Module C's Dependency. (HiveConf)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskAttemptContext
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.createShim(ShimLoader.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars.<clinit>(HiveConf.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.<clinit>(HiveConf.java:108)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 18 more
```

After I add this dependency in B, it works.

I do not think it is the right way. How can Module B deal with the dependences in Module C?

THX

Answer (score 0):

I've made a mistake.

The pom.xml of module C (utils) misses the dependency `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core`

It works now.